# ACF to select posts not displaying on blog page

Tags: posts, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to implement a repeater / post object so I can select posts that I want to displaying on the sidebar. I am using this code:

```
<?php while ( have_rows('top_posts_repeater')) : the_row(); // loop through the repeater fields ?>

<?php // set up post object
    $post_object = get_sub_field('selection');
    if( $post_object ) :
    $post = $post_object;
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>

<article class="your-post"> 

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php // whatever post stuff you want goes here ?>

</article>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code works if I insert it on any page but it doesn't work if I insert it in the blog page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `global $post;`  before your loops might do the job